# Architecture or flow diagram of Content rendition server in EMC Documentum

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, documentum-dfs

1. How does a content rendition server works in EMC Documentum? I tried to check in EMC Documentum sites but I couldn't find any satisfactory architecture diagram of the flow.
2. How a rendition request is processed and what is the role of the Adlib services in content transformation in EMC Documentum?

Can someone provide some explanations about this flow and architecture of CTS in EMC Documentum?